# Python: Convert str format to callable method

Tags: python, string, methods, pygame, callable

I do not quite know what to google to find a solution for my problem so I will try to find it here.

I am creating a Gui in Python 3.5.2 with pygame. I am currenctly working on Error popups that have a different button function depending on the error that is popping up. I want to give the function that is supposed to be executed as an argument in another class.

Code looks something like this:

```
def i_want_to_call_this(self):
  print("Button works.")

def button_with_action(self, action):
    self.button(self.action)
```

The other class will give the argument for which function the button will have like this:

```
popup_instance.popup_with_action(i_want_to_call_this)
```

The problem however is that the argument is parsed into string format and is not callable.

Comment: show `button` code - maybe it expects text as first argument to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what the methode `button` does (I guess that it binds to a given button the callable that is passed as argument), but you should consider using [`getattr`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm), to be able to call a function by using its name, passed as string, as follows

```
def button_with_action(self, action):
    dyn_created_callable = getattr(self, action)
    self.button(dyn_created_callable)
```

Of course nothing stops you from doing directly

```
def button_with_action(self, action):
    self.button(getattr(self, action))
```

That you would then use by doing

```
#...
    self.button_with_action('i_want_to_call_this')
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! It is working fine.

Comment: Was waiting for it to be possible. You answered to fast. :)